# installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, dplyr

Currently running ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.

A few days ago, dplyr was running flawlessly, but "disappeared" from my Package list (RStudio Version 0.98.1049).

Tried to reinstall dplyr from CRAN and got the following:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘/home/stu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘lazyeval’ is not available
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dplyr_0.3.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 643851 bytes (628 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 628 Kb

ERROR: dependency ‘lazyeval’ is not available for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/home/stu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/dplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpwxSL1L/downloaded_packages’
```

I really like dplyr and dread losing access. Can someone help me out? Thanks.
- Stu

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `dependency ‘lazyeval’ is not available for package ‘dplyr’`.  Did you try installing lazyeval?

Comment: Which leads to realizing that you may need R 3.1.* which one gets from CRAN for Ubuntu too, see the R FAQ.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and upgrading to R 3.1.2 solved it. (I followed this http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-r-base-3-1-0-ubuntu-14-04/ instructions without any problems.)